# How to properly use Sidekiq to process background tasks in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sidekiq, shopify-app

So, i've generated a rails app using https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app - and for the most part have the app working as intended - it's goal is to get product quantities from an external stock management API, and then update the variant quantities in Shopify with the latest quantities from that stock management system.

My problem is that the initial `POST` request to the external API responds with a large number of products - this takes upwards of 15 seconds sometimes. In addition to this, another portion of my app then takes this response, and for every product in the response that also exists in Shopify, it will make a `PUT` request to Shopify to update the variant quantities. As with the initial request, this also takes upwards of 10-15 seconds.

My problem is that i'm hosting the app on Heroku, and as a result i've hit their 30 second request timeout limit. As a result I need to use a background worker to offset at least one of the requests above (perhaps both) to a worker queue. I've gone with the widely recommended Sidekiq gem - https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq - which is easy enough to set up.

My problem is that I don't know how to get the results from the finished Sidekiq worker job, and then use that again within the Controller - I also don't know if this is best practice (i'm a little new to Rails/App development).

I've included my controller (prior to breaking it down into workers) that currently runs the app below - I guess I just need some advice - am I doing this correctly - should some of this logic be inside a Model, and if so how would that model then communicate with the Controller, and then how would Sidekiq then fit into all of it.

Appreciate any advice or assistance, thanks.

```
class StockManagementController < ShopifyApp::AuthenticatedController

require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'json'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'rexml/document'

def new
    @token = StockManagementController.new
end

def get_token

    url = URI('https://external.api.endpoint/api/v1/AuthToken')
    http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
    http.use_ssl = true
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

    @HEROKU_ENV_USERNAME = ENV['HEROKU_ENV_USERNAME']
    @HEROKU_ENV_PASSWORD = ENV['HEROKU_ENV_PASSWORD']

    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url)
    request['content-type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    request['cache-control'] = 'no-cache'
    request.body = 'username=' + @HEROKU_ENV_USERNAME + '&password=' + @HEROKU_ENV_PASSWORD + '&grant_type=password'
    response = http.request(request)
    responseJSON = JSON.parse(response.read_body)
    session[:accessToken] = responseJSON['access_token']

    if session[:accessToken]
        flash[:notice] = 'StockManagement token generation was successful.'
        redirect_to '/StockManagement/product_quantity'
    else
        flash[:alert] = 'StockManagement token generation was unsuccessful.'
    end
end

def product_quantity

    REXML::Document.entity_expansion_text_limit = 1_000_000

    @theToken = session[:accessToken]

    if @theToken

        url = URI('https://external.api.endpoint/api/v1/ProductQuantity')
        http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
        http.use_ssl = true
        http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

        request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url)
        request['authorization'] = 'bearer ' + @theToken + ''
        request['content-type'] = 'application/xml'
        request['cache-control'] = 'no-cache'

        response = http.request(request)
        responseBody = response.read_body
        finalResponse = Hash.from_xml(responseBody).to_json
        resultQuantity = JSON.parse finalResponse

        @connectionType = resultQuantity['AutomatorResponse']['Type']
        @successResponse = resultQuantity['AutomatorResponse']['Success']
        @errorResponse = resultQuantity['AutomatorResponse']['ErrorMsg']

        productQuantityResponse = resultQuantity['AutomatorResponse']['ResponseString']
        xmlResponse = Hash.from_xml(productQuantityResponse).to_json
        jsonResponse = JSON.parse xmlResponse

        @fullResponse = jsonResponse['StockManagement']['Company']['InventoryQuantitiesByLocation']['InventoryQuantity']

        # This hash is used to store the final list of items that we need in order to display the item's we've synced, and to show the number of items we've sycned successfully.
        @finalList = Hash.new

        # This array is used to contain the available products - this is used later on as a way of only rendering
        @availableProducts = Array.new

        # Here we get all of the variant data from Shopify.
        @variants = ShopifyAPI::Variant.find(:all, params: {})

        # For each peace of variant data, we push all of the available SKUs in the store to the @availableProducts Array for use later
        @variants.each do |variant|
            @availableProducts << variant.sku
        end

        #Our final list of products which will contain details from both the Stock Management company and Shopify - we will use this list to run api calls against each item
        @finalProductList = Array.new

        puts "Final product list has #{@fullResponse.length} items."
        puts @fullResponse.inspect

        # We look through every item in the response from Company
        @fullResponse.each_with_index do |p, index|

            # We get the Quantity and Product Code
            @productQTY = p["QtyOnHand"].to_f.round
            @productCode = p["Code"].upcase

            # If the product code is found in the list of available products in the Shopify store...
            if @availableProducts.include? @productCode
                @variants.each do |variant|
                    if @productCode === variant.sku
                        if @productQTY != 0
                            @finalProductList << {
                                "sku" => variant.sku,
                                "inventory_quantity" => variant.inventory_quantity,
                                "old_inventory_quantity" => variant.old_inventory_quantity,
                                "id" => variant.id,
                                "company_sku" => @productCode,
                                "company_qty" => @productQTY
                            }
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end

        # If we get a successful response from StockManagement, proceed...
        if @finalProductList
            flash[:notice] = 'StockManagement product quantity check was successful.'

            puts "Final product list has #{@finalProductList.length} items."
            puts @finalProductList

            @finalProductList.each do |item|

                @productSKU = item["sku"]
                @productInventoryQuantity = item["inventory_quantity"]
                @productOldInventoryQuantity = item["old_inventory_quantity"]
                @productID = item["id"]
                @companySKU = item["company_sku"]
                @companyQTY = item["company_qty"]

                url = URI("https://example.myshopify.com/admin/variants/#{@productID}.json")

                http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
                http.use_ssl = true
                http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
                request = Net::HTTP::Put.new(url)
                request["content-type"] = 'application/json'
                request["authorization"] = 'Basic KJSHDFKJHSDFKJHSDFKJHSDFKJHSDFKJHSDFKJHSDFKJHSDFKJHSDFKJHSDF'
                request["cache-control"] = 'no-cache'
                request.body = "{\n\t\"variant\": {\n\t\t\"id\": #{@productID},\n\t\t\"inventory_quantity\": #{@companyQTY},\n\t\t\"old_inventory_quantity\": #{@productOldInventoryQuantity}\n\t}\n}"

                # This is the line that actually runs the put request to update the quantity.
                response = http.request(request)

                # Finally, we populate the finalList has with response information.
                @finalList[@companySKU] = ["","You had #{@productOldInventoryQuantity} in stock, now you have #{@companyQTY} in stock."]

            end

        else
            # If the overall sync failed, we flash an alert.
            flash[:alert] = 'Quantity synchronisation was unsuccessful.'

        end

        # Lastly we get the final number of items that were synchronised.
        @synchronisedItems = @finalList.length

        # We flash this notification, letting the user known how many products were successfully synchronised.
        flash[:notice] = "#{@synchronisedItems} product quantities were synchronised successfully."

        # We then pretty print this to the console for debugging purposes.
        pp @finalList

    else

        flash[:alert] = @errorResponse

    end
end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your `product_quantity` method is way too long. You should break it into smaller parts. 2nd, `http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE` should not be done in production.  The example you've provide along with your question are too complex and are therefore difficult to answer.  It sounds like you need a basic understanding of design patterns and this is not a specific ruby question.

If your app needs to make realtime API calls inside of a controller this is a poor design.  You don't want to keep requests of any kind waiting for more than a couple of seconds at most.  You should consider WHY you need to make these requests in the first place.  If it's data you need quick access to, you should write background jobs to scrape the data on a schedule and store it in your own database.

If a user of your app makes a request which needs to wait for the API's response, you could write a worker to handle fetching the API data and eventually send a response to the user's browser probably using [actioncable](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actioncable/).

For your constant definitions you probably should do this in an initializer wihich you would keep in `my_app_root/config/initializers/constants.rb` which get loaded into your app at runtime.  You could just call them where need using te `ENV[]` syntax but if you prefer simpler constants drop the `@` since that naming convention in ruby is for instance objects.

```
#app_root/config/initializers/constants.rb
HEROKU_ENV_USERNAME = ENV['HEROKU_ENV_USERNAME']
HEROKU_ENV_PASSWORD = ENV['HEROKU_ENV_PASSWORD']
```

Comment: Hi @lacostenycoder - thanks for your feedback - its definitely my intention to write workers to handle fetching the API data - I guess the crux of my question would be - if I had written workers - how would I get data from the worker response back to the user's browser - you're suggesting this is possible with actioncable? Edit: To elaborate - I was planning on adding a worker to get the initial token. Then another worker to get the product quanity, and yet another worker to update the quantities in Shopify.

Comment: yes, that's probably the easiest way for rails.  Otherwise you'll have to have some kind of javascript polling to the job status and do something when the job is finished.

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for the actioncable and design pattern advice - broke the app up into models, got the logic out of the controller, and used sidekiq workers in tandem with actioncable messaging to achieve what I wanted.

Comment: @Marko glad this helped you. If you haven't already, you might wanna look at using OAUTH for api authentication instead of rolling your own.  https://help.shopify.com/api/getting-started/authentication/oauth